# Can Gaussian fucntion linear combination be super-Oscillatory

Tags: geometric-optics

Can the state
$$\psi =N [e^{-(x-ie^{i\phi}\alpha)^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}+e^{-(x+ie^{i\phi}\alpha)^{2}/2\sigma^{2}} + e^{-(x-e^{i\phi}\alpha)^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}+e^{-(x+e^{i\phi}\alpha)^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}]$$
be super-oscillatory? If yes how do I check for it?

I have already plotted local wave vector which shows peaks outside the range of the Fourier domain. But confusion is that, as Gaussian function never goes to zero before infinity. So how can we say from the Fourier spectrum that the function is super-oscillatory. I am not sure. Please anyone can explain this.

Comment: What does "super-oscillatory" mean?